# npm start - npm ERR! missing script: start

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm receiving this error when trying to my node application using the npm start command.

WhenIi try to npm start I get this error.

Error:

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'start' ]
    2 info using npm@5.6.0
    3 info using node@v8.10.0
    4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
    4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
    4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
    4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
    4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:402:5
    4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:357:45)
    4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:400:3)
    4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
    4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
    4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
    4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
    5 verbose cwd B:\tut\starter
    6 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
    8 verbose node v8.10.0
    9 verbose npm  v5.6.0
    10 error missing script: start
    11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

From the debug file:

```
{
  "name": "sridhar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "landing page",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss  css/style.css -w"
  },
  "author": "sridhar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the entry `start` in the `scripts` section of your `package.json`. If you want to compile the file using `npm start` then, you should copy `node-sass sass/main.scss  css/style.css -w` and paste it as a value for `start`. You can add any command you would like to execute as the value for start.

Having said that, if you do `npm "compile:sass"` it will compile your sass files if you don't want to change your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss  css/style.css -w",
     "start": "node-sass sass/main.scss  css/style.css -w"
  },
```

Comment: I have no error, but the file is not running. and showing like this  sridhar@1.0.0 start B:\tut\starter
> node-sass sass/main.scss  css/style.css -w "8200"

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, but I disagree with your assertion that “it is very clear”. It is not at all clear the this is the root cause. The `npm` scripts mechanism violates the principle of least surprise by treating some script keys as privileged (`start`, `test`, etc), but not others. `yarn` does a good job smoothing over this discrepancy.

Comment: I removed the assertion to avoid any disambiguity. Thanks for pointing it out @JoelCornett!

Comment: @sridharan, you mean `npm start` does not compile your file?

Comment: Thanks, It's compiling now, but I don't know the localhost port to view the page.may i know the default port?

Comment: There is no default port. It depends on your server configuration. Do you have a `server.js` file?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no start script...  Just change compile script to start script... Then it will compile your sass files...

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node-sass sass/main.scss  css/style.css -w"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

npx proved to be more effective to me, instead of using npm after several trials.

The below code worked for me:

npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod

It did not require me to manually edit the package.json anymore. Everything went smooth.

For more information please refer to the official documentation page https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `npx` and just use `create-react-app itworks`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove whatever is there in the script object (If you have just created the project) in package.json file, and put these two lines in.

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
"build": "webpack --mode production"`

Folks forget to do that sometimes.And leave the "test" case in. Also make sure you have installed all the dependencies you need for your project, from webpack-cli to other stuff mentioned in the error stack trace.

Hope this works.